# Почему в шаблонизаторе django не отображается изображение

Tags: django

Появилась проблема. Нужно вывести изображение курса. В модели использовал ImageField. В settings.py прописал media_url и media_root. Но все равно не изображение не отображается.

settings.py

```
    MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
    MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

models.py

```
    course_photo = models.ImageField(null = True, upload_to = 'courses/')
```

html. Здесь 'c' это модель переданная в views

```
    <p><img src = "{{ MEDIA_URL }}{{ c.course_photo.url }}" width='220' height='220'></p>
```

urls.py

```
    from django.urls import path
    from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
    from . import views
    from django.conf.urls.static import static
    from django.conf import settings

    app_name = 'mpage'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.mpindex, name = 'mpindex'),
        path('mpcourses/', views.mpcourses, name = 'mpcourses'),
        path('mpteachers/', views.mpteachers, name = 'mpteachers'),
        ]
```

Comment: urls покажите..

Comment: Во-первых, уберите `{{ MEDIA_URL }}` из шаблона, во-вторых, [подключите media в файле urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development)

Comment: все сделал но отображается только рамка изображения а самого изображения нет

Comment: Посмотрите в разметке страницы какой URL сгенерировался и, что происходит при попытке его открыть.

Comment: Сгенерировался вот такой http://127.0.0.1:8000/mpage/mpcourses/courses/icon.png. Странно ведь фото находится media/courses/icon.png